# Correct abstraction for DocumentFilter in JTextField

Tags: java, forms, swing, jtextfield, documentfilter

I have a few text fields which all get an int number.
If some field X wasn't filled- the user supposed to get a message: "You must fill in all the fields".
each field gets different values of numbers (field1 gets number between 1-100, field2 gets numbers between 2-20, etc.)
I need a suggestion for an abstraction of the DocumentFilter- what is more  correct- to add a TextFieldsFilter that extends DocumentFilter and then Field1Filter that extends TextFieldsFilter or Field1Filter that extends DocumentFilter  (and re-write the methods that check if the input is null, etc.?

Comment: Separate your responsibility. Use the `DocumentFilter` to do it's job, filter the input, use a `InputVerifier` to verify the input (post validation), but, you might consider simply have a button, which when clicked, checks all the fields for valid values before proceeding, as getting a message each time you leave a field would very, very annoying

Comment: Now, if you really want something fancy, have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274566/how-can-i-change-the-highlight-color-of-a-focused-jcombobox/25276658#25276658) which simply uses a `JXLayer` to show fields which are invalid, its none intrusive to the user, but provides excellent feedback

Comment: @MadProgrammer 
it's exactly what I do, when I click on a button called "Generate" it starts to check all the fields.
the JXLayer seems like a good idea, I will look into it.